# Dot-product a list of Matrices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, numpy-ndarray, numpy-einsum

Let's generate a 'list of three 2x2 matrices' that I call M1, M2 and M3:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(4*2*2).reshape((3, 2, 2))
```

I want to take the dot product of all these matrices:

```
 A = M1 @ M2 @ M3
```

What's the easiest and fastest way to do this? I'm basically looking for something similar to '.sum(axis=0)', but for matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`np.linalg.multi_dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html):

```
arr = np.arange(3*2*2).reshape((-1, 2, 2))
np.linalg.multi_dot(arr)
```

Will give you the dot product between `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`. As would `arr[0] @ arr[1] @ arr[2]`.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: For 3 arrays `multi_dot` uses `np.linalg.linalg._multi_dot_three` which does `dot(dot(A, B), C, out=out)` (or the alternate grouping if shapes differ).  So if the arrays are all the same shape, `multi_dot` is no better a chained `dot` (or `@`).